# get all instances from related models

Tags: django

I have one problem
Looking below:

I have this model:

```
class Shoes(models.Model):
    shop            = models.ForeignKey(Store, related_name="%(class)s")
    name            = models.ForeignKey(ShoesItem)
    size            = models.ManyToManyField(ShoesSize, help_text=_("Get useful sizes")) 
    price           = models.IntegerField()
```

in my case, I have models ShoesSize for store all ShoesSize and ShoesItem for store this Item

How can I get all sizes and all shops from ShoesItem instance?
there are (not full, for example):

```
class Store(models.Model):
    name            = models.CharField(max_length=255) 


class Item(models.Model):
    name            = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    brand           = models.ForeignKey(Brand, related_name="%(app_label)s_%(class)s")  
    sysname         = models.SlugField(max_length=255) 

    has_shop        = models.BooleanField(editable=False, default=False)
    description     = models.TextField(blank=True, verbose_name="Описание")
    color           = models.ManyToManyField(Color, blank=True, related_name='%(app_label)s_%(class)s')
```

and I get list of instances of Item models. After that, I want to get all available sizes and shops for all kind of items

Comment: please post `models` for `ShoesItem` and `ShoesSize`

Comment: You might want to rename class 'Shoes' to 'Shoe' and 'size' to 'sizes' since a single 'Shoe' object can have multiple 'sizes'.

Comment: If you are creating an e-commerce solution I can warmly recommend the Satchmo project - http://www.satchmoproject.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a reverse query by using the model name.

Get a ShoesItem:

```
shoes_item = ShoesItem.objects.all()[0]
```

Get ShoesSize objects for the ShoesItem via Shoes object:

```
sizes = ShoesSize.objects.filter(shoes__name=shoes_item)
```

Get Store objects for the ShoesItem via Shoes object:

```
shops = Store.objects.filter(shoes__name=shoes_item)
```

See more - [Lookups that span relationships](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships)

For a queryset of ShoesItem:

```
shoes_items = ShoesItem.objects.filter(has_shop=True)
sizes = ShoesSize.objects.filter(shoes__name__in=shoes_items)
shops = Store.objects.filter(shoes__name__in=shoes_items)
```